# bootstrap switch does not work with cdn

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've met an odd bug. I use bootstrap switch to make a checkbox on my site as a switch.

but, when I use cdn to reference the js and css file, it does not work. I have to use local file. Note that bootstap file with cdn works very well.

This works:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bootcss.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link href="css/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But this does not work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.bootcss.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="http://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap-switch/2.0.1/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: My antivirus detected this as a virus:

    http://cdn.bootcss.com/bootstrap-switch/2.0.1/css/bootstrap3/bootstrap-switch.min.css

Comment: well, it's just a cdn service in China, it can't be a virus